# Oracle: Translate subselect into pipelined function?

Tags: oracle, pipelined-function

How do I generically translate a subselect into a pipelined function call?

For example how would I translate this:

```
select id, stuff from t1 where id in (select unique id from kw where k = 'foo')
```

to this:

```
select id, stuff from t1 where id in (select id from table(has_kw('foo'))
```

Comment: Are both of those queries supposed to be `id in (subquery)` rather than `id = (subquery)`?  So you're just asking how to write the pipelined table function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing the pipelined table function is relatively straightforward

```
CREATE TYPE num_tbl AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE FUNCTION has_kw( p_k IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN num_tbl
  PIPELINED
IS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM kw WHERE k = p_k)
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW( i.id );
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
```

Now, I'm not sure that it would really make a whole lot of sense to use a pipeliend table function here.  But perhaps your actual use case is more complicated and a pipelined table function would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Justin... you're right, my application is more complicated.  This is a perfect minimal example.  All other examples I could find also created a row type, and had more gratuitous processing in the body of the function.